# Scientific Linux / CentOS Screen sharing

Tags: centos, gnu-screen, vnc

we have Scientific Linux 7 PCs. At one of them I cannot activate the "screen sharing" under "Settings"- "Sharing". I tried to disable / enable the "sharing". I can activate and deactivate the ssh but no the screen sharing. The button in the green frame cannot be switched to "on". Any ideas how to proceed?
I already tried:

- check `/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@service`
- check `$USER/.vnc`
- check `/root/.vnc`

should I delete all the vnc related file? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run vncserver manually:

```
x0vncserver -PasswordFile=~/.vnc/passwd
```

Comment: thank you, now I can connect (after having reset the password file) but unfortunately I only see a white-black densely dotted/mash screen. I still do not see the real screen if I do it from ssh.
If I start from the PC itself it works.